# Unexpected space mobile view

Tags: wordpress, mobile

I'm using Visual Composer for Wordpress in a website I'm building. However, in the mobile view, a space appears that makes the website horizontally scrollable. It happens in any theme, I've created a page where I stripped out just about everything, but the error stays... It can't possibly be the plugin, cause I use it on several other wesites. Am I missing something obvious?

http:// www. url .com/pagina2/

I hope someone spots what's going wrong, it's been driving me crazy..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually disable this with css with:

```
body { 
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

This will disable all the scrolling horizontally, since it will stop anything overflowing your containers.

This is caused by the `margins` you've got on `.vc_row wpb_row vc_row-fluid`. So you can either remove those `margins` or use the `overflow-x: hidden` option.

Add this in the head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```

This will make sure your window will contain itself in the window of your mobile browser.

Comment: Hi Kevin, thanks for taking a look at the issue. The overflow-x:hidden solution will hide the problem on the desktop, but your mobile phone will actually display an empty 10px (or something like that) on the right side of the screen. 

The margins on the .vc-row can't be the real issue, because those are generated bij Visual Composer (the plugin I use for creating columns). That code should be sound.

Comment: I've added another solution which might help :) but the margins might also be an issue. Because it is from a plugin does certainly not mean there can't be an issue with.

Comment: Hi Kevin, you're absolutely right, that really depends on the plugin and the developer. I use this plugin in many other websites though and they don't seem to have the issue. Hiding the symptoms of the problem also works great for me, so I'll accept your answer in a minute. Thanks for your ideas!

Comment: You are welcome! I'm also not quite sure why they do add that margin to such a container. They should leave that up to the developer to decide, but I'm glad I could be of assistance.